# Angular - bundle error on page reload with route parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Angular 4

I'm getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error from my bundles, but only in a specific situation:

- on live server only (nginx forwarding all traffic to express server, config below)
- only when refreshing routes that end on a route param, e.g. `chart/123`, where `123` is a chart id and the path is `chart/:id` in the router. Something like `/profile` works fine as this isn't a param in a route.
- **edit** - I also get this error for routes such as `users/add` and `organisations/add`, so it seems to error for any route with more than one 'part'...

The result is that all the `*.bundle.js` requests are returning the `index.html` file instead of their preferred `*.js` files.

Any ideas? Let me know if more context is needed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const rfs = require('rotating-file-stream');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

/**
 * Logging
 */

 /**
 * Create a logs directory (in project root)
 */
const logDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './logs');
if (!fs.existsSync(logDirectory)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);
}
// Set up rotating file stream, rotate every day
const accessLogStream = rfs('access.log', {
  interval: '1d',
  path: logDirectory,
});
// winston.info(logDirectory);
app.use(morgan('short', { stream: accessLogStream }));

/**
 * /Logging
 */

app.use(compression());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send('index not found');
  }
});


app.listen(port,'127.0.0.1');
console.log(`listening on 127.0.0.1:${port}`);
```

Here is my angular-cli.json (pretty much boilerplate):

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "new-client"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
         "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "livedata": "environments/environment.livedata.ts",
        "production": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for me, the issue was **conflicting base-href options**.

In my index.html, I have the standard `<base href="/">` option.

Then, in my build step, I had this:

```
ng build --environment=production --base-href . --aot
```

note the `--base-href .` - this seems to have been overriding the `/` option in the index.html. I solved by removing `--base-href` from my build script. I could have also set it to `./dist` to remove the conflict I think.

From the [angular-cli docs for `build`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build),  this setting overrides any option in your `index/html`.